# How to continue an HTTrack mirroring session from the command line?

Tags: httrack

I want to drive my mirroring project using the Command Prompt instead of the WinHTTrack interface so that I can script and schedule the mirroring session more easily.

The output of `httrack --help` gives a simple command for continuing an interrupted mirroring session:

```
example: httrack --continue
continues a mirror in the current folder
```

When I try `httrack --continue` in my HTTrack project folder, all I get is output like this:

```
Example: -%F "<!-- Mirrored from %s by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2010], %s -->"
* Option %F needs to be followed by a blank space, and a footer string
```

With each parameter on a new line for readability, the first line of my `doit.log` file looks like this:

```
-qiC1%P0s0b0u1j0%s%u0N0%I0p1DaK0c1T30H0%kf2E1800A25000%c0.1%f#f 
-F "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)" 
-%F "" 
-%l "en, en, *" 
http://saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=council_tax&SEARCH_TERM=City+of+Edinburgh&DISPLAY_COUNT=100 
-O1 
"C:\\Users\\Iain\\Projects\\Council Tax Analysis\\Code\\HTTrack\\Council Tax Valuation List" 
-* \
+*search.php?SEARCHED=1* 
-*DISPLAY_MODE=FULL*
```

The parameter `%F ""` should tell HTTrack to use an empty footer.

I used the WinHTTrack interface to create the project and start the mirroring session. I can interrupt and continue the mirroring session using the interface.

WinHTTrack saves the HTML files without a footer.

Answer (score 3):

I worked around the problem by removing the `%F` option from `doit.log`.

Now `httrack --continue` does continue to mirror my project.

After the mirroring session ended, the console output looked like this:

```
Mirror launched on Sat, 24 Nov 2012 19:22:10 by HTTrack Website Copier/3.46+htsswf+htsjava [XR&CO'2010]
mirroring http://saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=council_tax&SEARCH_TERM=City+of+Edinburgh&DISPLAY_COUNT=100 -* +*search.php?SEARCHED=1* -*DISPLAY_MODE=FULL* with the wizard help..
Done.
Thanks for using HTTrack!
```

HTTrack has added a footer to the new files:

```
<!-- Mirrored from saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=council_tax&SEARCH_TERM=City+of+Edinburgh%2C+EDINBURGH&DISPLAY_COUNT=100&PAGE=0&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=C&ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=City+of+Edinburgh&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=CLAREMONT+GARDENS%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=CLAREMONT+GARDENS by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2010], Sat, 24 Nov 2012 19:52:28 GMT -->
```

I didn't really want the footer, but at least I can control HTTrack from the Command Prompt.